# Reminders.app UIScrollView scrolling explanation.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiscrollview

I am currently programming an application for the iPhone and I am having some **issues with my horizontal (horizontal as in you scroll horizontally, not vertically) UIScrollView.**

The `UIScrollView`'s **height is 260** and the **width is 320.** It has 2 pages and each page has a `UITableView` in it. The `UITableView`'s frame is the same as the `UIScrollView`'s frame.

The problem is that **80% of the time**, the current `UITableView` detects the drag/swipe as a vertical scroll (but it's actually horizontal) and begins to scroll the table view vertically.

**My question is the following:**

Can somebody explain to me how the app Reminders does for the scrollview scrolling. If you look carefully, you can see that the scrollview handles the horizontal scrolling very well and that a horizontal scroll is handled by the scrollview (and not by the tableview like mine does). **If anyone needs more explanation please leave a comment.**

Comment: Was this issue ever resolved? I too am curious how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I try to scroll to the left/right in the table view of Reminders, it doesn't respond to it. If I scroll in the table header view where the add button is, it scrolls without any problems. My guess is that they made the table view header a UIScrollView. Apple highly discourages the use of a table view in a scroll view (or any view that inherits from UIScrollView into a different view that inherits from UIScrollView, for that matter), so they probably wouldn't take their own advice and ignore it.

Comment: Nesting UIScrollViews is often the right approach. I've never heard of Apple discouraging it.

Comment: From the UIWebView class reference: `You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled.` I guess I assumed this applied to all classes that inherit from UIScrollView (+ UIWebView)

Comment: I know i shouldn't be doing that, but I /have/ to. Do you have any idea of how to do this?

Comment: Is a simple swipe gesture recognizer sufficient?

Comment: Add two (left and right) swipe gesture recognizers to your table view, then set up a method that detects those recognizers. In that method you do what you want to do with a horizontal swipe (e.g., the Reminders app switches views).

Comment: I add the gesture recognizers to the table view? Not the scrollview?

Comment: The whole point is to avoid a scroll view and have the gesture recognizers instead.

Comment: Or just add gesture recognizers to the scrollview and set scrollEnabled to NO?

Comment: No, forget about the scroll view. A table and two gesture recognizers is all you need.

Comment: I always like Ray Wenderlich's tutorials. Check out this one for example: http://www.raywenderlich.com/6567/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-in-ios-5-pinches-pans-and-more. It doesn't cover the swipe gesture recognizer specifically, but it explains the general idea of a gesture recognizer very well. Look at the Apple docs for the available properties on UISwipeGestureRecognizer, too.

Comment: I know how to use gesture recognizers, i just do not know how to integrate it with the tableview and still have 2 pages...

Comment: Add both pages to the view. One at the currently visible frame (x= 0), the other at x= +320 or -320 (depending on if you want the currently invisible page to the left or right). When you detect a swipe, you simply set the frames of the two views to -320 (for a left swipe) or +320 (right swipe). You can animate this if you like. The only thing you won't have is "partial" scrolling, as is the case on Springboard, for example. Then again, the Reminders app doesn't have that either.